# UWP not syncing visibility when rendering a png

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Well. I have an async method in my class that just save all the content of an stackpanel to a PNG file. So I follow some logic displayed below:

- Export the stackpanel png
- Hide some labels and display other ones
- Export the stackpanel again

All of this is inside my method, but I'm having problems with this visibility. After hiding/showing (visibility = Visibility.Collapsed), seems the visibility doesn't change in time to be rendered on the png. So doing this away above, the labels sometimes are displayed and sometimes don't on the last export. But if I put some delay between them, it works:

- Export the stackpanel png
- Hide some labels and display other ones
- await Task.Delay(1000)
- Export the stackpanel again

So I'm pretty sure after I'm changing visibility stuff, is taking some time to update the UI itself. How can I wait for the UI changes so I can make sure my second export will only be performed when everything is ready?

Note: All this logic is inside one single async function that uses await for EVERY async call inside it. The problem is in fact when I made updates like visibility and try to render to the png file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual changes happen the next time the UI thread "ticks" - it is not immediate. The easiest way to wait for the next tick is to use [`Dispatcher.RunAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-18362#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunAsync_Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcherPriority_Windows_UI_Core_DispatchedHandler_) which should schedule your code for the next tick, at which point the `Visibility` will have changed.

There will be a visual 'flash' as the user sees the UI Elements disappear and then reappear.

Comment: I removed the Delay instruction and added this block of code:
`
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                ;
            });
`
This runs right after changing the visibility attribute, but even using await seems I'm having the same problem.

Comment: You need to put all the code in the `RunAsync` block - the `await` completes when the code is queued for dispatch, not when it finishes executing.